# How to make the delete button delete the right post?

Tags: python, django

I have this delete button with a dialog on it but the button does not get the id of the post right and whatever i do it writes the title of the same post every time and I think it always starts to delete from the first post so I end up deleting them all and when I click to delete a post it gives this error what should I do?

If I need to post another part of code please let me know

Thanks in advance

**ValueError at /posts/delete/105
The view posts.views.delete didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

views.py

```html
from django.forms.models import BaseModelForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from users.models import Profile
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

  



def detail(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)
     return render(request, "posts/detail.html", {"post": poost})

@login_required()
def delete(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)
     if request.user == post.author:
          poost.delete()
          messages.error(request, f'Post deleted!')
          return redirect("/")

@login_required()
def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         form = PostForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
              form.instance.author = request.user
              form.save()
              messages.success(request, f'Post created!')
              return redirect("/")   
           
    else:
         form = PostForm()
    return render(request, "posts/new.html", {"form": form })
```

post.html (where delete button is)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg 3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div style="margin-top: 25px"></div>
      <div class="card-deck text-center">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-header" id="linkilink">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{post.title}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
          {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30 }}
          <hr>
          <p> <a href="{% url 'userinfo' post.author.id %}"><img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="75" height="75"></a> <div style="color: rgb(133, 131, 131);"> Author: {{ post.author }} </div> </p>

        
          <a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" id="readbutton">Read More <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"/>
            </svg></a>
            


          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          {% if user == post.author%}
          
          <a href="{% url 'update' post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" >Edit</a>


              <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" id="deleteButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
                  <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
                </svg></a>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          </div>
      </div>
    

      {% if user == post.author%}
      <div>
        <body>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
              <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="icon-box">
                </div>              
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>  
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p  class="text-muted">Do you really want to delete {{ post.title}}? This process cannot be undone.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>     
        </body>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

detail.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<html>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
  <body class="text-left">
    <article>
      <h1 style="font-family: Georgia, serif;">{{post.title}}</h1>
      <a style="margin-top: 15px; font-size: larger;">{{post.body|linebreaks}}</a>
    </article>
  </body>

  <div style="margin-top: 30px"></div>
  <p  style="text-align: center;">
    <a style="color: darkgray; font-size: 22px;"> <img  src="{% static 'website/icons8-sparkles-25.png'%}"> Written by {{post.author}} <img  src="{% static 'website/icons8-sparkles-25.png'%}"> </a>
  </p>
  
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your delete button `<a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>` performs a GET, which should not be deleting (GET is supposed to leave everything unchanged, and you can get all sorts of odd cacheing errors). It's not the source of your problem, but you need to delete using a POST (maybe a CBV DeleteView to keep it short)

Comment: if I want to change it without using a class based view what should I do?? I mean instead of that  `poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)`  what should I put there??

Comment: Wrap it in a `<form>` with no fields except for csrftoken which specifies `method="post"`. You can pass `post.id` as the value of the button and retrieve it in `delete` as `request.POST['button-name']`. But it's really so much easier to just use CBV DeleteView.

Answer (score 0):

The delete view in views.py has a condition that checks if `request.user == post.author`. However, `post` is not defined in this context as your varvname is `poost` (most likely a typo), which breaks the execution flow.